# Checkout Process By Credit Card On localhost without any API or extension

Tags: checkout, payment, payment-methods

Is it possible to perform payment by credit card on my localhost without any extension or API?

How can I set this up? If it is not possible without an extension what are my options?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Saved CC" payment method which you can find under System > Configuration > Payment Methods.

In the order view details in Admin Backend, your orders will show the credit card details entered (number, name, expiration date). You are responsible to take this information and charge your customers using this details with your service of choice (which you have obviously not connectend to magento then).

Be aware that storing CredidCard Data in your shop requires good security and that you need to become PCI-DSS compliant. This is one of the reasons, why integrating with a payment service provider who offers credit card payment makes sense and the details won't be stored in your shop then.

Edit:

You might also be interested in this article on magentocommerce: [How can I capture credit card information without a payment gateway?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-can-i-capture-credit-card-information-without-a-payment-gateway1)

For testing, you might not use real credit card data, but some test credit Card account numbers, which you can find here:
http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm